# How can I determine the default encoding in a portable class library?

Tags: c#, encoding, portable-class-library

With `.NET 4.6` I can detect the current codepage with:

```
System.Text.Encoding.Default
```

Now I'm trying to port a class library that is reading files from a standard class library to a portable class library, supporting ASP.NET Core 5. With this configuration, `Encoding.Default` is not availiable.

Of course, any recent file should be saved in `UTF-8` encoding, but I can not ensure that all files are stored in this encoding.

Is there another way to get the default codepage?

I looked at [the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/encoding.cs,1c75de327ad88c0a,references) and found that `Encoding.Default` is implemented (more ore less) with an Win32 Api call...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation here: [Encoding.GetEncoding Method (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzsz3bk3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), you can use Encoding.GetEncoding(0) to get the default encoding.

Comment: And it works at least under `.NET 4.6` and universal windows apps. I couldn't test it with a `.NET Core` console operation - didn't have enough patience with Visual Studio..